# 'Declined to authorize this image on this device for this user.' when attempting to restore iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, itunes, restore, kernel-panic

I'm trying to restore my Gen 1 iPad Pro to a previous version of iOS because the current version (16.4) causes a kernel panic due to the device running out of memory. However when I try to attempt to load any previous version I'm confronted with the 'Declined to authorize this image on this device for this user.' error message.

I checked my /etc/hosts file and there are no entries for gs.apple.com.

Does anyone have any suggestions?